# I can't find the Id of a ContextMenuItem

Tags: c++, winapi, contextmenu, menustrip

I have an emulator that has ContextMenu and MenuStrip elements that I want to access to automate actions, but analyzing it with Spy++ (32bit) it is impossible for me to find their id to be able to call them with `SendMessage()`.

I tried filtering the `WM_COMMAND` messages, but I get nothing that I understand, and that is why I need help to solve this problem.

[image]

Here is a link to the emulator with which I am working:

https://mega.nz/file/tYoFiahB#SG9q6r88v-VfHVZuN_15LpVX06bh7SUYQZFWLPnC8O0

Comment: There is a `WM_COMMAND` message in the screenshot you provided. What do its `wParam`/`lParam` parameters look like? For a menu action (`HIWORD(wParam)=0` and `lParam=0`), the menu item's ID is in `LOWORD(wParam)`, per the [`WM_COMMAND` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command) (also see [Restating the obvious about the WM_COMMAND message](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060302-10/?p=32093))

Comment: Beware also that if an application uses its own UI framework (such as Qt), you might not get any relevant messages for the window you're trying to examine.

Comment: The app may use `TrackPopupMenu` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenu with `TPM_RETURNCMD`, and then perform whatever action without sending any messages.